# How do I make Java plug-in classes task dependent upon my own task?

Tags: gradle

Gradle is giving me fits.  I have a build.gravle that includes the java plug-in and I have built a task within it that generates a properties file and drops it into the build/classes directory.  This all works like a champ.  Here is my custom task.

```
task generateBuildSignature << {
    def whoami = System.getProperty( 'user.name' );
    def hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    def buildTag = System.env.BUILD_TAG ?: "dev"

    ant.propertyfile( file: "${buildDir}/buildsignature.properties", comment: "This file is automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT!" ) {
        entry( key: "version", value: "${project.version}" )
        entry( key: "buildTimestamp", value: "${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')}" )
        entry( key: "buildUser", value: "$whoami" )
        entry( key: "buildSystem", value: "$hostname" )
        entry( key: "buildTag", value: "$buildTag" )
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the execution of this task integrated into the Java build lifecycle, preferably immediately after processResources or as a dependency of classes, but I'm at Chapter 23 of the documentation http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html and it is not yet clear exactly how get my task into the dependency chain of the task(s) that come in through the java plug-in.  Any advice for a fledgling gradle user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to (and can) do is to add a task dependency. For example:

```
classes.dependsOn(generateBuildSignature)
```

Comment: That'll work.  My problem was I had the clases.dependsOn(generateBuildSignature) in my build.gradle file immediately before the task declaration for generateBuildSignature.  This was producing "Could not find property 'generateBuildSignature' on task ':classes'." FAILUREs.  switching these two around in the build.gradle file (task generateBuildSignature << {...} then classes.dependsOn(generateBuildSignature)) gets everything working as planned.  Thanks.

Comment: Gradle accepts multiple representations for a task. To depend on a task that has not been declared yet, you can use `classes.dependsOn("generateBuildSignature")`.